# print in MIPS the corresponding HI and LO number

Tags: printing, mips, multiplication

does someone know how to print HI and LO correctly when you make the multiplication in MIPS?. The HI and LO works as 64bits register, but the read print syscall only works with 32 bits. I need create a code to print the correponding HI LO number.

Comment: Write your own `int_to_string` function that handles 64-bit values.

Comment: yeah. but the number are separated in two register.

Comment: example: HI: 0x00000009 that means(9 in decimal)
LO: 0x502f9000 that means( 1345294336 in decimal)
But the number i want to print is: 0x9502f9000 that means 40000000000 in decimal